# processing multimillion tweets

Tags: python, bigdata, nltk

I am trying to analyze the tweets data.
One of the issues that I am facing in this point is the size of data and cleaning.
However, even few thousand tweets, it takes long time to analyze. I think there might be some way to save the time and hope to what other people think to improve.

I think one way to improve is purge the list under self. Currently, under the directory I have eight files.

```
def main(mode=1):
    for filename in os.listdir(readDir):            
        filename = os.path.join(readDir, filename)
        print(filename)
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in filename:

                print('Proccessing File is: ', filename)
                keyword=text.textAnalyze(filename)
                print(keyword)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



import nltk, json, os, csv, matplotlib, pylab, re, sys, numpy
from nltk import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from os import listdir

#Global Empty List must be called


#Cleaning List
cleaningList=set(['t.co/','//t.co/','http','#','@','RT','w/','//t','//...RT',':',';',',','.'])
keywordFilter=set(['pie','juice','cinnamon','fruit','slice','eat'])
nounList=['samsung','android']

#Loading the JSON
#filelist=[os.listdir("/Users/ArnoldChung/Documents/test")]
#print (filelist)

class textAnalysis():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tweets=[]
        self.tweetsE=[]
        self.tweetsPOS=[]
        self.tweetsFBK=[]
        self.tweetsADJ=[]
        self.hashtagList=[]

    def textAnalyze(self, filename):
        #filename='%s' %json
        for line in open(filename, 'r'):
            try:
                self.tweets.append(json.loads(line))
            except:
                pass

        #tweetsE is the list of tweets filtered by English.
        for tweet in self.tweets:
            if tweet['lang']=='en':
                try:
                    self.tweetsE.append(tweet['text'])
                except IndexError as e:
                    pass

        #tweetsPOS is the list of tweets which word is tagged by nltk.pos_tag(universal tagger)
        for tweet in self.tweetsE:
            include = True
            for word in keywordFilter:
                if tweet.count(word) > 0:
                    include = False
                    break
            if include == True:
                words=word_tokenize(tweet) #words = Class List
                wordTag=pos_tag(words) # wordTag
                for word, tag in wordTag:
                    self.tweetsPOS.append((word, map_tag('en-ptb', 'universal', tag)))

        #tweetsFBK is the list of tweets which excludes retweets, hashtag, and external links.        
        for (word, tag) in self.tweetsPOS:
            include = True
            #word = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' ', word)
            for key in cleaningList:
                if word.startswith(key):
                    include = False
                    break
            if include == True:
                self.tweetsFBK.append((word,tag))

        # Adjective cleaner for mismatched word 
        for index, (word,tag) in enumerate(self.tweetsFBK):
            for key in nounList:
                    if word.startswith(key):
                        self.tweetsFBK[index] = (word, 'NOUN')

        for (word, tag) in self.tweetsFBK:
            if tag == 'ADJ':
                self.tweetsADJ.append(word)

        fd=nltk.FreqDist(self.tweetsADJ)
        fd=fd.most_common(20)
        return fd
```

Comment: Without your data set, how can people help you to speed this up? I think you either need to provide a data set and/or (preferably) limit the question to a much smaller piece of code with a specific question in mind.

Comment: @Paul Frankly speaking, the data that I want to parse is 16gb which I cannot upload to anywhere....